# A less verbose way to throw when a boolean Mono is a certain value

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a lot of cases where boolean variables begin a reactive sequence and in case they are a certain value (mostly false) an exception is supposed to be thrown and the sequence broken. For example

```
Mono.just(foo.isValid())
    .flatMap(b -> b ? Mono.empty() : Mono.error(new FooNotValidException(foo.detail1, foo.detail2)))
    .then(bar.doProcess())
    .flatMap(b -> b ? Mono.empty() : Mono.error(new BarProcessingNotSuccessful(bar.detail1, bar.detail2)))
    ....
```

Here if `foo` is not valid `bar` is not executed and sequence is broken with a detailed exception, same if `bar` processing fails.

that up there is the shortest i managed to get it to, but there is a lot of repetition so i am wondering if this can be made any less verbose?

Comment: You seem to be using `boolean` to signal success of operations and throwing. I would remove all that logic and just throw in `isValid` and `doProcess` then perhaps use `onErrorMap` to remap the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Borises comment i rewrote the above code example to

```
Mono.fromRunnable(foo::isValidOrThrow) // may throw FooNotValidException    
    .then(Mono.fromRunnable(bar::doProcessOrThrow)) // may throw BarProcesingNotSuccessful 
    ....
```

This looks much nicer.